# CheckedChange method to a mutiple amount of checkboxes

Tags: c#, dynamic, checkbox

Is there any possible to access to the CheckedChanged Event to handle all checkboxes, when they are changed?

```
private void AddTask(int member, String bound)

    // ...
     for (int i = 1; i <= bound; i++) {
         CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                    checkBox.Name = String.Format("c_Mem{0}_A{1}", member, i);
                    checkBox.Text = "";
                    checkBox.Width = 20;
                    checkBox.Height = 15;
                    checkBox.Location = new Point(boundX_ChkBox, boundY_ChkBox);
                    boundX_ChkBox += 26;

    //...
    }
    }
```

I tested following, which doesnt worked for me. (I just tried to check for one checkbox, which should be actually later in a loop)

```
  private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if ((CheckBox)this.Controls["c_Mem1_A1"]).Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you add the event handler to the dynamic `CheckBox`es?

Comment: u mean checkBox_CheckedChange? I added this just after my function AddTask()

Comment: Can you explain this sentence? "to handle all checkboxes, when they are changed", you wanna do something when all checkbox are checked?

Comment: @Tinwor, nope.. i have a few of checkboxes, in the end there must be a counter which counts at runtime how much checkboxes are pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to cast the `sender` argument of the event to `CheckBox`:

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) sender;
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test"); 
    }
}
```

But you first need to add the same event handler:

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
// ...
checkBox.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
```

Comment: but where I use my checkbox names?

Comment: @AlbertFragt: what do you mean? You can use `String name = cb.Name;`. You haven't mentioned that the name has a special purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop where you are creating the checkboxes, you can assign a single event handler for all check boxes. This is how it can be done:

```
checkBox.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
```

If this is a windows forms application, you can assign a unique number to `Tag` property. This can be then used to track checkboxes. Or else, you can also use `switch` on name. Your handler will then look like this:

```
void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox currentCheckBox = (CheckBox)sender;

            switch ((int)currentCheckBox.Tag)
            {
                case 1:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // do something else
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwer, but where I use my check box names, which I terminated when I generated my checkboxes.

Comment: What do you mean terminated? Is the name relevant? Do you need to do same processing for all checkboxes?